# A C-embedded subset is a C*-embedded subset?

Tags: general-topology

Let be $(X,\tau)$ a topological space and $S\subset X$.
If $S$ is C-embedded set of $X$ then $S$ is C*-embedded set of $X$.

Here is my atempt:

Let $f\in C^{*}(S)$, but we know that $C^{*}(S)\subset C(S)$ then $f\in C(S)$. By hypothesis $S$ is C-embedded in $X$, so there is a $F\in C(X)$ such that $F_{|_{S}}=f$.

As $f\in C^{*}(S)$ $\Rightarrow$ exists $n\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that $\forall x\in S$, $|f(x)|\leq n$. We define the following function as follows

$F^{*}:=(-\widehat{n}\vee F)\wedge \widehat{n}$ where the functions $-\widehat{n}$ and $\widehat{n}$ are defined $\forall x\in X$, $\widehat{n}(x)=n$, $-\widehat{n}(x)=-n$.

Clearly $F^{*}\in C(X)$

Also $F^{*}_{|_{S}}=f$ since $\forall x\in S$ $\Rightarrow$ $F^{*}(x)=(-\widehat{n}(x)\vee F(x))\wedge \widehat{n}(x)=(-n \vee f(x))\wedge n$

Let´s remember that $\forall x\in S$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f(x)|\leq n$ then $-n\leq f(x)\leq n$ so we get $(-n\vee f(x))=f(x)$ and $f(x)\wedge n=f(x)$

Finally we get $\forall x\in S$

$F^{*}(x)=(-\widehat{n}(x)\vee F(x))\wedge \widehat{n}(x)=(-n \vee f(x))\wedge n=(f(x))\wedge n=f(x)$

But my problem is here, I can´t prove that $F^{*}\in C^{*}(X)$ if someone knows how prove it, please give me a clue

Comment: the proof is contained in the first two sentences of your attempt

Comment: @ForeverMozart i don´t undestand how the proof is contained in the first two sentences of my attempt!!!
In this two sentences i have that $F$ is a continuous extension of $f$ and $f$ is a bounded function on $S$. 
Please!!! could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you want the extension to be bounded.

Let $m$ and $M$ be lower and upper bounds for $f$, respectively.

Let $F:X\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous extension of $f$.

We use the fact that the min/max of two continuous functions is continuous.

Let $F':=\min\{F,M\}$. Note that  $F':X\to (-\infty,M]$ is a continuous extension of $f$.

$F^*:=\max\{F_1,m\}$. Then $F^*:X\to [m,M]$ is a continuous extension of $f$.

EDIT: Your proof is correct. You just have to see that $F^*$ is bounded because $−\hat n(x)∨F(x)\geq -n$ (assuming that $∨$ means max) and then you minimized that with respect to $n$.

Comment: ahhhhhhh ok!!! i already undestand!! thanks